# Json key unable to access key value

Tags: node.js, json

I will be getting a dynamic json as response, so I am using the below to get the key names and I always want the third key value which will either be true or false. So i get the third key's value using the below which is stored inside the theTypeIs and when I try to access the json I get undefined

example Json

```
submitResult = [{
        ComodityID: 33,
        ComodityName: 'LED',
        field1: true
    }, {
        ComodityID: 342,
        ComodityName: 'Installing ',
        field1: true
    }, {
        ComodityID: 322,
        ComodityName: ' Bracket',
        field1: true
    }
]
```

To find the third key name in the dynamic json:

```
var theTypeIs = Object.keys(submitResult[i])[2];
console.log(submitResult[i].theTypeIs)
```

I get undefined when i console log it. Can someone help me on this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: By the way, you should note that `Object.keys` doesn't guarantee the order. So you may get unexpected results. Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219 for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log(submitResult[i].theTypeIs)` prints `undefined`because there is no property `theTypeIs` of `submitResult[i]`

You need to use the bracket notation when accessing an attribute by a variable

```
console.log(submitResult[i][theTypeIs])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the bracket notation:

```
console.log(submitResult[i][theTypeIs]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
enter code
```

```html
const submitResult= [{ ComodityID: 33, ComodityName: 'LED', field1: true }, { ComodityID: 342, ComodityName: 'Installing ', field1: true }, { ComodityID: 322, ComodityName: ' Bracket', field1: true }]


//To get the third key which is field1

you can run a loop i to length
const {field1} = submitResult[i];
```

Comment: That code snippet doesn't run correctly. Please fix it, and also add text to describe why it answers the question.